# Use facebook's php SDK to retrieve email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

So far i have it set up to retrieve basic user info, nothing extended. Im trying to get the user email as well, with no success. Here's what i got:

```
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            'cookie' => true,

        ));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!empty($session)) {
    try {
    $params = array(
      'scope' => 'email',
      'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.dormduels/splash_test'
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();

         $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

        echo $access_token;
        $user = $facebook->api('me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,username,email&access_token='.$access_token);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user);
        exit();
```

The problem is. the getAccessToken that its displaying, when tested in facebooks graph explorer, doesnt show extended data like email, only basic. How do i request a more permission enabled acces token?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), namely "email" for here in one of the following ways:

1. **php sdk**

   Use the [getLoginUrl()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) method of the sdk object, and specify the extended permissions you need in the 'scope', and redirect the user to its return value, Also you need to add the domain and the site url in your [facebook app's admin page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). Here's an example:

   ```
   define('APP_ID', 'TODO FILL IT WITH YOURS');
   define('APP_SECRET', 'TODO FILL IT WITH YOURS');

   require_once 'facebook.php';

   function redirect_to_login($fb){
       $login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
           'scope' => 'email',
       ));
       header('Location: '.$login_url);
       exit;
   }

   $fb = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => APP_ID,
       'secret' => APP_SECRET,
       'cookie' => true,
   ));

   $uid = $fb->getUser();
   if (!$uid || !check_perms($fb, $uid, array('email'))) { // see check_perms below
       // send users to login/auth page if they are not logged in, 
       // or not installed the app, 
       // or don't have all the perms we need
       redirect_to_login($fb);
   }

   try {
       $me = $fb->api('/me');
       var_dump($me);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       redirect_to_login($fb);
   }
   ```
2. **js sdk**

   Use the [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) function to ask for the extended permissions you need, in the second parameter.

For detailed information on the whole authentication process, see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/).

If you want to check if the current user has the all the permissions you want, you can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) like this:

```
function check_perms($facebook, $uid, $perms = array()) {

    $perms_str = join(' = 1 and ', $perms).' = 1';
    $query = "select uid from permissions where uid = '".$uid."' and ".$perms_str;

    try {
        $row = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query'  => $query,
        ));
        return $row && $row[0]['uid'] == $uid;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*note:*
Your [php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) version probably is outdated, the getSession() method have been deprecated in favor of getUser() / getAccessToken()

Comment: Updated my question with getLoginUrl with no luck

Comment: I think you might put it in a wrong place (the example is a syntax error in this case anyways) you should put the getLoginUrl() call in the else block of the `if ($facebook->getUser()) { ...`, also simply invoking it won't redirect the user to the url its returning. You need to issue a http header or other way to send the browser there like `header("Location: ".$loginUrl);`

Comment: updated to the new sdk, you were right i was outdated ANd moved the getloginurl into the if get user but still... nothing... no access token with permissions is being givin

Comment: I've added a full example, tested with the sdk version 3.1.1, I hope this will help

Comment: Assuming the fb user is logged in the first time with basic permissions set, why would the redirect_to_login() function with the scope ever be called? We need the original facebook call to include a scope

Comment: This is where the second example with the permission checking could come into play, you can check the user's permission if you got an uid back from `getUser()`, or you can call `redirect_to_login()` if the `api('me')` fails to return the email field. If the user is already logged in and installed your app, facebook only propmt the permission changes to her, or if nothing changed just redirects back.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, i do it this way:

```
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_API_KEY,
  'secret' => FB_API_SECRET,
));

// Get User ID
$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $fb_user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
if ($fb_user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $fb_user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($fb_user) {
    $fb_loggedin = true;
} else {
    $fb_loggedin = false;
    $fb_loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'email,user_location',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/debut_'.($lang == 'fr' ? 'fr' : 'eng').'.php'
    ));
}
```

The SCOPE in the getLoginUrl is what you want to look at, you can see all the different permissions on the developer site at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Good luck

Comment: But shouldnt the scope be defined under new facebook?

Comment: Never defined it there, but i might do it incorrectly too, i'm just showing you the way i do it and it works...

Comment: But that getLoginUrl is only be called if the user isnt logged in. Which never happens bc i have a new facebook/getuser, which prompts the user to log in

Answer (score -1):

```
Try following:
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

 public function login() {
        $loginUrl= $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email',
                    'redirect_uri' => 'your redirectUri',
                    'display' => 'popup'
                ));
       header("Location:$loginUrl");
    }
public function fUserInfo() {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        //check permissions list
        $permissions_list = $facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'GET', array('access_token' => $access_token));
        $permissions_needed = array('email');
        foreach ($permissions_needed as $perm) {
            if (!isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1) {
                login();
            }
        }
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {
            try {
                $userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                Config::getLogger()->debug($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        print_r($userInfo);
    }
```